# How to make TAB work right in Command Window?

Tags: windows-xp, command-line

When I press TAB key in command window, the tab character (spacing) is inserted instead of iterating trough items in current directory. How can I make it work this other way (autocompletion)?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It looks like completion may be disabled in the Registry.

There's an explanation below, from the output of `cmd /?`:

File and Directory name completion is NOT enabled by default.  You can enable or disable file name completion for a particular invocation of CMD.EXE with the /F:ON or /F:OFF switch.
You can enable or disable completion for all invocations of CMD.EXE on a machine and/or user logon session by setting either or both of the following REG_DWORD values in the registry using REGEDT32.EXE *(actually, just regedit.exe would be fine)*:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\CompletionChar
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\PathCompletionChar

    and/or

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\CompletionChar
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\PathCompletionChar
```

with the hex value of a control character to use for a particular function (e.g.  0x4 is Ctrl-D, 0x6 is Ctrl-F, 0x9 is Tab).  The user specific settings take precedence over the machine settings.  The command line switches take precedence over the registry settings.

If completion is enabled with the /F:ON switch, the two control characters used are Ctrl-D for directory name completion and Ctrl-F for file name completion.
To disable a particular completion character in the registry, use the value for space (0x20) as it is not a valid control character.

Comment: You can also set both of these options using TweakUI: http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/downloads/powertoys/xppowertoys.mspx

Comment: @njd, Why do you say  that it's not enabled by default? It seems to be enabled by default for me (Win 8.1).

Comment: @Pacerier It's not enabled by default in Windows XP, which is the version the OP was asking about. Also I wrote that in 2010 and Windows 8 didn't get released until 2012.

Comment: @njd, Anyway, another oddity: `Ctrl-F` and `Ctrl-D` **both** cycles through files and folders. Basically they do the same thing, is that the behavior you have on win8.1 too?

Comment: Likewise, to set Tab as the completion character, set the values of both CompletionChar and PathCompletionChar to '9' (ASCII code for Tab in both decimal and hex).

Comment: Is there a easier way?  A UI way of doing this.

Comment: I'm working on a windows 10, and was using the auto-completion tab with no issues, sometime in the last few months (perhaps due to an OS update) it stopped working, when I checked it I saw it had the `@` sign as the value for both keys,  
tried to use it and no auto-completion.

It might be that auto-completion isn't possible with multiple-keys-combination,  
when I tried the tab (vertical tab) with hex/dec value of 9 it worked.

Answer (score 3):

To make TAB default for auto complete follow below

1. open REGEDIT
2. look for HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\CompletionChar
3. change the value to 9
4. restart the cmd
5. That's it.

Comment: Worked for me! The value was 40 before, then I changed it to 9. I hope I didn't disable anything important thereby.

Answer (score 0):

For me I had to :

- right-click on the title bar
- select **Properties**
- check **QuickEdit Mode** under **Edit Options**

Answer (score 0):

On my system, adding the /F option to the command-prompt link disabled tab completion, regardless of what value was given. If I don't give /F at all, I have tab completion; but /F:ON and /F:OFF both disable it.